# The clip-path inset method dosen't work in firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, clip-path

This is my css :

```
#aImages{

   clip-path: inset(70px 70px 70px 70px);
   position:relative;
   bottom:60px;
   right:39px;

}
```

I've been looking everywhere for a way to make my image the size I want, that works in Chrome AND firefox

Comment: Looks like It's not supported by Firefox.  See this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @trav The way I read it, the link says it _does_ work, as long as you set the pref to true. [Here, a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/kj8m4qg0/).

Comment: Unrefined, which version of Firefox are you testing on, and did you check if layout.css.clip-path-shapes.enabled was true?